# Redis ram jump and crash

Tags: redis

I use redis for storing statistics on my site , the usual trafic is about 1000-2000 redis calls per second, I recently migrated the website to another hosting service and I am experiancing problems with the redis-server , it seems that after about 6-12 hours of running it suddenly gets ram hungry till i crashes, In order to get it back I need to do a restart of the redis service.
I dont see anything unusual in the redis logs or the syslog

```
5274:M 17 Aug 14:55:26.006 * 10000 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
5274:M 17 Aug 14:55:26.023 * Background saving started by pid 12754
12754:C 17 Aug 14:55:30.823 * DB saved on disk
12754:C 17 Aug 14:55:30.838 * RDB: 24 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5274:M 17 Aug 14:55:30.925 * Background saving terminated with success
5274:M 17 Aug 15:07:40.615 # User requested shutdown... ->this is where I restart it
5274:M 17 Aug 15:07:40.615 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
5274:M 17 Aug 15:07:44.877 * DB saved on disk
5274:M 17 Aug 15:07:44.877 * Removing the pid file.
5274:M 17 Aug 15:07:44.878 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

This is the ram usage , it was about 9 gb before the crash and during the crash it suddenly went up to 13gb(with 20gb remaining free)

[image]

cpu system time(the user time was in normal levels)
[image]